# how to make backgroundImage fully displayed inside the box

Tags: html, css

I have two box with id `box1` and `box2`, I load images to box from an array `items` .

`url` of each item is added to `backgroundimage` of each box using for loop.

my problem is that the `backgroundImage` * is not being fully displayed inside the box*

how to make the `backgroundImage` fully visible inside the box?

```js
var array2 = [];

var items = [{
    label: 'first',
    url: 'https://i.ibb.co/0DvMRj4/wcheetah.png'
  },
  {
    label: 'second',
    url: 'https://i.ibb.co/gDqm8Dv/wcrow.png'
  },
];
var tempimages = [];
array2 = items.slice();
var item;

function displayimages() {

  boxtags = document.getElementsByClassName("box");

  for (let index = 0; index < 2; index++) {

    item = array2[index];
    //console.log(item);
    try {


      boxtags[index].style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + item.url + ')';
    } catch (err) {
      // console.log('Exception');
    }
  }
}

displayimages();
```

```css
#box1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: -10.3vh;
  left: -30.98vw;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 2px solid #0066CC;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

#box1 p {
  width: 10.0vw;
  height: 10.0vh;
  border-radius: 25%;
}

#box2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: -10.3vh;
  left: -10.98vw;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 2px solid #0066CC;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

#box2 p {
  width: 10.0vw;
  height: 10.0vh;
  border-radius: 25%;
}

#container {
  white-space: nowrap;
  border: px solid #CC0000;
}

.containerr {
  border: px solid #FF3399;
}

.container2 {
  width: 50.1vw;
  position: fixed;
  top: 10.5vh;
  left: 30.5vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="container2">
  <div class="containerr">

    <div id="container">
      <div class="box" id="box1">
        <p name="values" draggable="true" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="name1"></p>
      </div>
      <div class="box" id="box2">
        <p name="values" draggable="true" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="name2"></p>
      </div>

    </div>


  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try using background-size: contain edit: in box1 and in box2 instead of using cover

Comment: @camilo-go-jr worked perfect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to do what I think you want to do, you should use `background-size: contain;` instead of `background-size: cover;` in `#box1` and `#box2`.

`background-size: contain;` will scale the image so that each dimension is as large as possible without exceeding the corresponding dimension of the container.

`background-size: cover;` will scale the image to the minimum size needed for its dimensions to be equal to or greater than the corresponding dimensions of the container. In other words, it will be scaled so that it is as small as possible while still completely covering (and, in some instances, being cropped by) the container.

```js
var array2 = [];

var items = [{
    label: 'first',
    url: 'https://i.ibb.co/0DvMRj4/wcheetah.png'
  },
  {
    label: 'second',
    url: 'https://i.ibb.co/gDqm8Dv/wcrow.png'
  },
];
var tempimages = [];
array2 = items.slice();
var item;

function displayimages() {

  boxtags = document.getElementsByClassName("box");

  for (let index = 0; index < 2; index++) {

    item = array2[index];
    //console.log(item);
    try {


      boxtags[index].style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + item.url + ')';
    } catch (err) {
      // console.log('Exception');
    }
  }
}

displayimages();
```

```css
#box1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: -10.3vh;
  left: -30.98vw;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 2px solid #0066CC;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
}

#box1 p {
  width: 10.0vw;
  height: 10.0vh;
  border-radius: 25%;
}

#box2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: -10.3vh;
  left: -10.98vw;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 2px solid #0066CC;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
}

#box2 p {
  width: 10.0vw;
  height: 10.0vh;
  border-radius: 25%;
}

#container {
  white-space: nowrap;
  border: px solid #CC0000;
}

.containerr {
  border: px solid #FF3399;
}

.container2 {
  width: 50.1vw;
  position: fixed;
  top: 10.5vh;
  left: 30.5vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="container2">
  <div class="containerr">

    <div id="container">
      <div class="box" id="box1">
        <p name="values" draggable="true" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="name1"></p>
      </div>
      <div class="box" id="box2">
        <p name="values" draggable="true" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="name2"></p>
      </div>

    </div>


  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: background-size: contain; wokd perfect

Answer (score 0):

You can use `background-size: contain` instead of `cover` for `box1` and `box2`.